# Struct template where the number of constructor arguments is a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I am creating a templated vector struct (the math construct, not the STL container) where the type of data and number of elements are parameterized; i.e. Vector `<int,3>` stores three integers. I'd like to write a constructor that takes the parameterized-number-of-elements arguments and initializes the underlying array with them. I think I need to use a variadic template. This is my attempt:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int n>
struct Vector
{
  T data[n];

  explicit Vector(const T& fillVal)
  {
    std::fill(data, data+n, fillVal);
  }

  explicit Vector(T... args)
    : data(args...)
  {}
};
```

The compiler gives me the error that "'T': does not contain a parameter pack". How can I fix this to achieve my desired behavior? Also, do I need to test the type and number of arguments, and if so, how?

Comment: Do you know there is a `std::array` ?

Comment: @liliscent I didn't know about it until I read your comment - it's pretty cool. However, I'm adding functionality, like specializing Vector<T,2> to have a union of T data[2] and struct {T x,y}, so I don't think I can use std::array.

Comment: Do you know there is a `std::variant` ?

Comment: How about simply taking an independent pack of parameters and forwarding them into the array? The compiler will bleat if the counts don't match.